# Шифруются ли cookie с параметром secure=false на сайте работающем по https?

Tags: cookie, https

Насколько я понял, secure-куки отправляются на сервер только если он работает по https. Но как передаются незашифрованные куки на сайте работающем по https? То, что они все отправляются на сервер я уже понял, но отправляются как: шифруются все куки или только secure?

Comment: Куки отправляются внутри зашифрованного соединения при работе по хттпс.

Comment: Куки сами по себе никак не шифруются, шифруется соединение целиком при https, а куки (в том числе secure) передаются внутри этого зашифрованного соединения как обычно. Если https нету, то отправляются не-secure куки тоже как обычно, просто в незашифрованном соединении